# What does this dash mean in a like operator in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I was looking at some SQL code and I could not figure out what this dash means?

```
Label LIKE '%-#arguments.subscriberId#'
```

Comment: it's just a dash character!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you thought it had some kind of special meaning?

Answer (score -2):

It is to filter on barcode labels like so 1234-56789, 0923-56799
That query would return both if 567 was search on.

Comment: No, it would not match either of those. Since the expression only contains contains a leading wildcard ie `%`, it would only match values *ending with*  "-567" exactly.